# Is there a way to convert an SDL_Surface to a Raylib Texture2D?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

title says it all, just wondering if it's possible to convert an SDL_Surface to a Raylib Texture2D

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to do that... yet.

If you have the technical knowledge, you can try to write something that does what you want by analyzing the two classes (both of the libraries are open-source).